# Angular 2 - No errors, but application is not loading properly too

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular2-routing

I am new to angular and I have started angular 2. I have started sample project initially it was working fine, but suddenly it stops working. As it is not showing output into browser. Below is my code.

**index.html**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Bulletin Board</title>
  <base href="/">

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
</head>
<body>
  <app-root>Loading...</app-root>
</body>
</html>
```

**app.component.ts**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  constructor() {
  }
  title = 'app';
}
```

**app.module.ts**

```
const appRoute: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: '/login',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  },
  {path: 'login', component: UserComponent},
  {path: 'registration', component: UserRegistrationComponent}
];

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    UserComponent,
    UserRegistrationComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(appRoute),
    BrowserModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**EDIT**

**app.component.html**

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

**user.component.ts**

```
<div class="login-box">
  <div class="login-logo">
    <b>Bulletin</b>Board
  </div>
  <div class="login-box-body">
      <div class="form-group has-feedback">
        <input type="text" #txtUsername class="form-control" placeholder="Usrename or Email">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope form-control-feedback"></span>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group has-feedback">
        <input type="password" #txtPassword class="form-control" placeholder="Password">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock form-control-feedback"></span>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-8">
          <div class="checkbox icheck">
            <label>
              <input type="checkbox"> Remember Me
            </label>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-4">
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block btn-flat" (click)="onButtonClick(txtUsername.value,txtPassword.value)">Sign In</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    <a routerLink="/registration" class="text-center">Register a new membership</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Now I am not able to figure out that what is happening and what is error, and unable to get output.

What changes needs to do?

Comment: use <router-outlet></router-outlet> in app.component.html

Comment: @BrijalSavaliya Sorry it my mistake, I have used in app.component.html only.

Comment: is it working for you ?

Comment: No, it is not working.

Comment: What about UserComponent? Also,is localhost:4200/registration showing the content? (ie, if the app is running on localhost:4200)

Comment: @Gunner Application is running on localhost:4200 only. and localhost:4200 is not showing any content. I think code is fine but i made some mistake that i cannot able to find.

Comment: A plunker would be helpful.

Comment: any error on console ?

Comment: @RahulSingh no error in console, that is surprising.

Comment: Start using angular-cli

Comment: @wacky_coder try and use this in router `  redirectTo: 'login',` instead of  `  redirectTo: '/login',`

Comment: @RahulSingh done as you suggested, but did not work.

Comment: @wacky_coder hard to find anything if you can recreate a plunekr it will be great

Comment: @RahulSingh okay, Will notify once it will be done on plunker. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You dont have any script includes to load angular or any other script file. Most templates use the following setup in Index.html. Adjust according to your setup:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <base href="/">

    <!-- Polyfill(s) for older browsers -->
    <script src="node_modules/core-js/client/shim.min.js"></script>

    <script src="node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/reflect-metadata/Reflect.js"></script>

    <script src="systemjs.config.js"></script>
    <script>
        System.import('app').catch(function(err){ console.error(err); });
    </script>
</head>
```

Comment: I have tried above solution, and copied those scripts to angular-cli.json too. Didn't effect any thing.

Answer (score 0):

I did solve this query.

I just have to import `HttpModule` into `app.module.ts` file.
ie

```
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http'
```

and into `import` array,

```
imports: [
RouterModule.forRoot(appRoute),
BrowserModule,
HttpModule
],
```

so my entire ***app.module.ts*** would look like this.

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { Http, HttpModule } from '@angular/http';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { UserComponent } from './user-login/user.component';
import { UserRegistrationComponent } from './user-registration/user-registration.component';

const appRoute: Routes = [
  { path: '',
  redirectTo: 'login',
  pathMatch: 'full'
} ,
  { path: 'login', component: UserComponent},
  { path: 'registration', component: UserRegistrationComponent}
];

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    UserComponent,
    UserRegistrationComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(appRoute),
    BrowserModule,
    HttpModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

***Thank you guys, for helping.***